# Fastest way to save bitmap image to PDF using pdfsharp

Tags: image, pdf, bitmap, pdfsharp

I need to create a pdf file from several bitmap images. I am currently using the following code:

```
Dim size As New XSize(0,0)      
For k = 0 to theBMPList.Count-1
    Dim oPage As New PdfPage()
    doc.Pages.Add(oPage)
    Dim xgr As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage)
    Dim img As XImage = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(theBMPList(k))
    size = new XSize(theBMPList(k).Width, theBMPList(k).Height)
    oPage.Height = size.Height
    oPage.Width = size.Width
    xgr.DrawImage(img, 0,0, size.Width-5, size.Height-5)
Next
```

This works fine but is very slow. Is there a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: Run the code in a profiler, see where it loses time, and optimize that part. Feedback will be welcome.
Can you try `XImage.FromFile()` instead of `XImage.FromGdiPlusImage()`? Could make a difference - at least for some image types and some operating systems.

Comment: My images are in memory not in a file. So I cannot use the XImage.FromFile()

Comment: How about providing an MCVE with a few images so we can see why it is "very slow" and how to make it faster?

Comment: I can post a typical TIFF file but I do not know how to do that.